# Spring Rest passing parameter to exclude tag

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-restcontroller, spring-rest

I need to do a functionality to if I have for example the result of a get.

http://localhost/getData

And the result it's

```
    {"menu": {
      "id": "file",
      "value": "File",
      "popup": {
        "menuitem": [
          {"value": "New", "onclick": "CreateNewDoc()"},
          {"value": "Open", "onclick": "OpenDoc()"},
          {"value": "Close", "onclick": "CloseDoc()"}
        ]
      }
    }}
```

But imagine I would like to do this:

http://localhost/getData?exclude=id

And the id value dont appear on result. Or even if I want to do ?exclude=id,value,etc etc.. and the response hide it for me...
Imagine also I want to hide the sublist like all menuitem.

Using SpringMVC with Springboot what is the best way/pratices to do it?

Thank you everyone.

Comment: You can specify filters for Jackson before serializing your objects to json. See http://www.baeldung.com/jackson-serialize-field-custom-criteria

Comment: Hello Thoomas, thank you but I cannot implements that in every class on the system... there is some other way? Thanks